# Miller-Rabin primality test gives wrong answer

Tags: c++, primes, primality-test

I'm trying to make a RSA algorithm. For that i need rabin-miller+witness+modular exponentiation(at least I'm required to use that). The problem comes when i generate random numbers to check with rabin miller if they are primes, and the result is that non-prime numbers are prime for rabin-miller algorithm. Could somebody give me a hand to see where i fail.
Thanks in advance.

```
int mod_exp(int a, int b, int n){

    int d = 1,i,j=0;
    int binary[15];
    for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
        binary[i] = -1;
    }
    i=0;
    do{
        binary[i]=(b%2);

            if((b%2)==1)
                b=(b-1)/2;
            else
                b=b/2;
        i++;
    }while(b!=0);

    do{
        d= (d*d)%n;
        if(binary[i]==1)
            d=(d*a)%n;
        i--;
    }while(i!=-1);
    return d;

}

bool wittness(int a, int n){
    int u=n-1,k=0;
    long x, temp;
    while(u%2== 0 ){
        u=u/2;
        k++;
    }
    x=mod_exp(a,u,n);
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
        temp=x;
        cout<< "primera x:"<<x<<endl;
        x=long(x*x)%n;
        cout<< "segunda x:"<<x<<endl;
        if(x==1 && temp!=1 && temp != n-1)
            return true;

    }
    if(x!=1)
        return true;
    return false;

}


bool miller_rabin(int n, int s){

    int a,j;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(j = 0; j<=s;j++){

       a=rand()%s+1;
       if(!wittness(a,n))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I take it this is an exercise, rather than code you are planning to release in an actual product?  The former is fine; for the latter - just use a library written by experts!  (You can't write tests for "is this library insecure?")

Comment: I've just seen you are using "int" - which is usually 32bits.  Given that uint512_t is hopelessly insecure for RSA, this is *clearly* "exercise" not "production".

Comment: I thought everybody would undrstand when i said "(at least I'm required to use that)" sorry if you didnt. Yes, it´s an exercise and it works, i just had problems calling the functions. Thanks anyway to those who helped.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at all of the code, but your mod_exp function is certainly incorrect. The two expressions `(d*d)%n` and `(d*a)%n` are both susceptible to overflow, and if overflow occurs you will get an incorrect result.